# How to StartAcitivity from a fragment adapter

Tags: android, adapter, fragment

I have a list fragment with a custom adapter. This adapter has a onClick event of an image wherein I want to start an new intent (Activity). I am not able to do this.

Can any one please help me with the code.

```
viewholder.gMaps = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgMaps);
viewholder.gMaps.setClickable(true);
viewholder.gMaps.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Not sure how do I start an Activity");
        /*
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(((ListViewFragment) context), GMaps.class);
        intent.putExtra("Longitude", mList.get(holder.position).get("Longitude").toString());
        intent.putExtra("Latitude", mList.get(holder.position).get("Latitude").toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below code for people who are still searching for answer

```
holder.gMaps.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(v.getContext(), GMaps.class);
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", mList.get(holder.position).get("Longitude").toString());
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", mList.get(holder.position).get("Latitude").toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to setflag as a new Activity if you are calling startActivity() in outside of Activity class.

```
holder.gMaps.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(v.getContext(), GMaps.class);
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", mList.get(holder.position).get("Longitude").toString());
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", mList.get(holder.position).get("Latitude").toString());
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```